# Jquery call after passing into Url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my code

```
<a class="foot" href="<?php echo someurl.com?id;?>" >Info</a>
```

Iam setting a click function for the class 'foot'

```
$('.foot').click(function(){

alert('run some functions');
});
```

As you can see on the code above First it runs Jquery  later on it will be passed to specified Url... But is it possible to pass to specific url then run Jquery.. ???

Comment: when you change page the code execution can't continue, since you unload the document. You need to execute a script on the destination page

Comment: I'm somewhat confused with the question, but if you're asking if you can run the code after the page reloaded or changed, the answer is no. You have to run it before that.

Comment: i have to pass id to a different page before running the jquery...

Comment: May be you can go to the new page, include this page in the newer one and then run the functions on `document.ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Ajax request` if you want to call the URL without moving to another page. otherwise your javascript code won't execute.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

if you are doing this for a fallback in case your client doesn't support Javascipt then you have to do it like this.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your code
});
```

Comment: Yes iam Ajax is the  Solution for this, But iam using Zf2 and not sure how to use Ajax could not find much documents on ZF2 ajax , so i thought of trying this way.....

Answer (score 0):

if you want the code to run after page load then I suggest you introduce:

`$(document).ready(handler)`

That way jquery runs AFTER page load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prventDefaults and then trigger document.location.href to your clicked link.
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using $(document).ready(handler)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.foot').click(function(){
  alert('run some functions');
  });
});
</script>


<a class="foot" href="hello.php" >Info</a>
```